# Hyperlink doesn't redirect to View from same project

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to redirect from one view to another view in the same project/solution. There are 3 hyperlinks in here and I am unable to redirect to either of them. Can someone help me with this?

```
<body>
  <div>
    <br />
    <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
    <a href="~/Views/Corporation/ForgotLoginId.cshtml">Forgot Login ID?</a>
    <br />
    <br /><span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
    <a href="~/Views/Corporation/ForgotPassword.cshtml">Forgot Password?</a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
    Need to register your Corporation?
    <a href="~/Views/Corporation/CorporationRegistrationPg1.cshtml">Click here</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

When I try to click on the hyperlink, I am getting the following HTTP 404 Not Found error. I tried many approaches, but none seem to work.

[image: error]

I tried different approaches to linking to the controller. But, I failed to get any positive output.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net does not have phyiscal routing - you do not want to link to physical files. Instead it resolves its routes after a pattern. The default pattern, unless specified otherwise is `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`.

So assuming your controller is called CorporationController, and your action method is called "ForgotPassword", the hyperlink would be constructed with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "ForgotPassword", "Corporation")
```

You might want to read some basic documentation about Asp.Net Mvc first.

Comment: To expand on @Marco's suggestion: [Documentation for ASP.NET Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs); [Documentation for `ActionLink()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). If you're using ASP.NET Core, [the format is a bit different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1).